# PHP DOM Attribute Wildcard

Tags: php, dom, web-scraping

I have looked all around for this and I have been unable to find it. I simply want to select elements from html using a wildcard. For example, for the page I am scraping, this selector works perfectly in the console for Jquery:

```
$("tr[id^='informal_']")
```

In other words, grab all rows with an id starting with 'informal_'. I have tried xpath but have had no luck. Is xpath exclusive to XML? Anyway, if anyone has any solutions out there, I would greatly appreciate it.

**EDIT**

xpath I used:

```
  $doc = new DOMDocument($html);
  $doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
  $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
  $table_rows = $xpath->query("//*tr[starts-with(@id, 'informal_')]");
```

**SOLUTION**
I decided to go with: http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/

Here is the code:

```
require('phpQuery/phpQuery.php');

    $doc = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($html);;
    $table_rows = $doc->find("tbody tr[id^='informal_']");
```

Comment: can you show the xpath you used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent of the jQuery selector

```
tr[id^='informal_']
```

in XPath, is

```
//tr[starts-with(@id, 'informal_')]
```

You were super-close to the answer, it was only the `*` that got in the way.

Comment: Thanks man. In the end, I decided to go with http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/, but I appreciate that you actually gave me something instead of just telling me it was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`*tr` is invalid XPath as you're mixing the wildcard with a literal node name.

You need just `*`, i.e. `*[starts-with...`

Comment: I need to specify <tr> with attribute id='informal_...' though. So my path would be: `//tr*[starts-with(@id, 'informal_')]`?

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want just `tr` nodes, or nodes of any name?